# cvtColor crashing android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have been trying to get into OpenCV. The code below seems to be crashing on the cvtColor.

```
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray = inputFrame.gray();

        Mat gray = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

        return gray;
   }
```

I cant put my finger on why it keeps crashing the android app after the video runs for like 10 seconds, without the cvtColor it runs just fine.

Wondering what could be going on here.

Logs

```
 ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][ISP_BUF]-ERR(getBuffer[667]):increase the buffer failed, m_allocatedBufCount 8, bufferIndex -2
10-04 20:39:54.877  3105 22149 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1447]):Buffer manager getBuffer fail, manager(2), frameCount(686), ret(-22)
10-04 20:39:54.936  3105 22149 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][ISP_BUF]-ERR(getBuffer[667]):increase the buffer failed, m_allocatedBufCount 8, bufferIndex -2
10-04 20:39:54.936  3105 22149 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1447]):Buffer manager getBuffer fail, manager(2), frameCount(687), ret(-22)
10-04 20:39:54.996  3105 22149 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][ISP_BUF]-ERR(getBuffer[667]):increase the buffer failed, m_allocatedBufCount 8, bufferIndex -2
10-04 20:39:54.996  3105 22149 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1447]):Buffer manager getBuffer fail, manager(2), frameCount(688), ret(-22)
10-04 20:39:55.055  3105 22150 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1948]):frameCount(686) : captureNodeCount == 0 || checkRet(0) != NO_ERROR. so, setFrameState(FRAME_STATE_SKIPPED)
10-04 20:39:55.056  3105 22149 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][ISP_BUF]-ERR(getBuffer[667]):increase the buffer failed, m_allocatedBufCount 8, bufferIndex -2
10-04 20:39:55.056  3105 22149 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1447]):Buffer manager getBuffer fail, manager(2), frameCount(689), ret(-22)
10-04 20:39:55.056 25883 25883 E CocktailBarContainerView: updateContainerVisibility: 0
10-04 20:39:55.115  3105 22150 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1948]):frameCount(687) : captureNodeCount == 0 || checkRet(0) != NO_ERROR. so, setFrameState(FRAME_STATE_SKIPPED)
10-04 20:39:55.116  3105 22149 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][ISP_BUF]-ERR(getBuffer[667]):increase the buffer failed, m_allocatedBufCount 8, bufferIndex -2
10-04 20:39:55.116  3105 22149 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1447]):Buffer manager getBuffer fail, manager(2), frameCount(690), ret(-22)
10-04 20:39:55.131 25883 25883 E CocktailBarContainerView: updateContainerVisibility: 0
10-04 20:39:55.131 25883 25883 E CocktailBarPanelManager: updateCocktailDisplayPolicy: 128 ---> 128
10-04 20:39:55.131 25883 25883 E CocktailBarContainerView: updateContainerVisibility: 0
10-04 20:39:55.135 25883 25883 E CocktailBarContainerView: updateContainerVisibility: 0
10-04 20:39:55.158 26076 26076 E Zygote  : v2
10-04 20:39:55.160 26076 26076 E Zygote  : accessInfo : 0
10-04 20:39:55.176  3105 22150 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1948]):frameCount(688) : captureNodeCount == 0 || checkRet(0) != NO_ERROR. so, setFrameState(FRAME_STATE_SKIPPED)
10-04 20:39:55.176  3105 22149 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][ISP_BUF]-ERR(getBuffer[667]):increase the buffer failed, m_allocatedBufCount 8, bufferIndex -2
10-04 20:39:55.176  3105 22149 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1447]):Buffer manager getBuffer fail, manager(2), frameCount(691), ret(-22)
10-04 20:39:55.183 25883 25883 E CocktailBarPanelManager: updateCocktailDisplayPolicy: 128 ---> 1
10-04 20:39:55.184 25883 25883 E CocktailBarContainerView: updateContainerVisibility: 0
10-04 20:39:55.186 26087 26087 E Zygote  : v2
10-04 20:39:55.187 26087 26087 E Zygote  : accessInfo : 0
10-04 20:39:55.205  3105 26008 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.210  3105 22157 E Surface : queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
10-04 20:39:55.210  3105 26008 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.210  3105 22157 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(enqueueBuffer):enqueue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.210  3105 26008 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.210  3105 22157 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1866]):could not enqueue_buffer [bufIndex=1]
10-04 20:39:55.210  3105 26008 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.210  3105 26008 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.210  3105 26008 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: @@@@ERR(alloc):*bufHandle == NULL failed
10-04 20:39:55.210  3105 26008 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(dequeueBuffer):alloc failed
10-04 20:39:55.210  3105 26008 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_bufferCollectorThreadFunc[2294]):dequeueBuffer failed, dequeue(6), collected(4)
10-04 20:39:55.214  3105 26102 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.214  3105 26102 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.214  3105 26102 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.214  3105 26102 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.214  3105 26102 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.214  3105 26102 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: @@@@ERR(alloc):*bufHandle == NULL failed
10-04 20:39:55.214  3105 26102 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(dequeueBuffer):alloc failed
10-04 20:39:55.215  3105 26102 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_bufferCollectorThreadFunc[2294]):dequeueBuffer failed, dequeue(6), collected(3)
10-04 20:39:55.217  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1420]):Pipe is Busy, Skip frame, frameCount(679)
10-04 20:39:55.219  3105 26103 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.219  3105 26103 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.219  3105 26103 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.219  3105 26103 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.219  3105 26103 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.219  3105 26103 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: @@@@ERR(alloc):*bufHandle == NULL failed
10-04 20:39:55.219  3105 26103 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(dequeueBuffer):alloc failed
10-04 20:39:55.219  3105 26103 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_bufferCollectorThreadFunc[2294]):dequeueBuffer failed, dequeue(6), collected(2)
10-04 20:39:55.223  3105 26104 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.223  3105 22157 E Surface : queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
10-04 20:39:55.223  3105 22157 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(enqueueBuffer):enqueue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.224  3105 26104 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.224  3105 22157 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1866]):could not enqueue_buffer [bufIndex=2]
10-04 20:39:55.224  3105 26104 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.224  3105 26104 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.224  3105 26104 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.224  3105 26104 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: @@@@ERR(alloc):*bufHandle == NULL failed
10-04 20:39:55.224  3105 26104 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(dequeueBuffer):alloc failed
10-04 20:39:55.224  3105 26104 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_bufferCollectorThreadFunc[2294]):dequeueBuffer failed, dequeue(6), collected(1)
10-04 20:39:55.225  3105 26105 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.225  3105 26105 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.225  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_getCollectedBuffer[2397]):Gralloc buffer collector has no Buffer
10-04 20:39:55.225  3105 26105 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.225  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_getCollectedBuffer[2421]):Failed to get available gralloc buffer from buffer collector, available count(0)
10-04 20:39:55.225  3105 26105 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(getBuffer[611]):m_getBuffer failed [bufferIndex=-2, position=2, permission=0]
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 26105 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1447]):Buffer manager getBuffer fail, manager(5), frameCount(683), ret(-38)
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 26105 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: @@@@ERR(alloc):*bufHandle == NULL failed
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 26105 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(dequeueBuffer):alloc failed
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 26105 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_bufferCollectorThreadFunc[2294]):dequeueBuffer failed, dequeue(6), collected(0)
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_getCollectedBuffer[2397]):Gralloc buffer collector has no Buffer
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_getCollectedBuffer[2421]):Failed to get available gralloc buffer from buffer collector, available count(0)
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(getBuffer[611]):m_getBuffer failed [bufferIndex=-2, position=2, permission=0]
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1447]):Buffer manager getBuffer fail, manager(5), frameCount(684), ret(-38)
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_getCollectedBuffer[2397]):Gralloc buffer collector has no Buffer
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 26107 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_getCollectedBuffer[2421]):Failed to get available gralloc buffer from buffer collector, available count(0)
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(getBuffer[611]):m_getBuffer failed [bufferIndex=-2, position=2, permission=0]
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1447]):Buffer manager getBuffer fail, manager(5), frameCount(685), ret(-38)
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 26107 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 26107 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 26107 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 26107 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(alloc):dequeue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 26107 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: @@@@ERR(alloc):*bufHandle == NULL failed
10-04 20:39:55.226  3105 26107 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(dequeueBuffer):alloc failed
10-04 20:39:55.227  3105 26107 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_bufferCollectorThreadFunc[2294]):dequeueBuffer failed, dequeue(6), collected(0)
10-04 20:39:55.227  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1410]):New frame is INVALID, frameCount(686)
10-04 20:39:55.227  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1410]):New frame is INVALID, frameCount(687)
10-04 20:39:55.227  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1410]):New frame is INVALID, frameCount(688)
10-04 20:39:55.236  3105  3382 E CameraService: notifyError(CAMERA_MSG_ERROR, CAMERA_ERROR_RELEASED)
10-04 20:39:55.236  3105 22150 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1948]):frameCount(689) : captureNodeCount == 0 || checkRet(0) != NO_ERROR. so, setFrameState(FRAME_STATE_SKIPPED)
10-04 20:39:55.236  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1410]):New frame is INVALID, frameCount(689)
10-04 20:39:55.243  3105 22157 E Surface : queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
10-04 20:39:55.243  3105 22157 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(enqueueBuffer):enqueue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.243  3105 22157 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1866]):could not enqueue_buffer [bufIndex=3]
10-04 20:39:55.260  3105 22157 E Surface : queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
10-04 20:39:55.260  3105 22157 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(enqueueBuffer):enqueue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.260  3105 22157 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1866]):could not enqueue_buffer [bufIndex=4]
10-04 20:39:55.288  3105 22157 E Surface : queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
10-04 20:39:55.288  3105 22157 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(enqueueBuffer):enqueue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.288  3105 22157 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1866]):could not enqueue_buffer [bufIndex=5]
10-04 20:39:55.296  3105 22150 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1948]):frameCount(690) : captureNodeCount == 0 || checkRet(0) != NO_ERROR. so, setFrameState(FRAME_STATE_SKIPPED)
10-04 20:39:55.296  3105 22151 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1410]):New frame is INVALID, frameCount(690)
10-04 20:39:55.317  3105 22157 E Surface : queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
10-04 20:39:55.317  3105 22157 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(enqueueBuffer):enqueue_buffer failed
10-04 20:39:55.317  3105 22157 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(m_putBuffer[1866]):could not enqueue_buffer [bufIndex=6]
10-04 20:39:55.343  3105 22152 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_ISP]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1948]):frameCount(683) : captureNodeCount == 0 || checkRet(0) != NO_ERROR. so, setFrameState(FRAME_STATE_SKIPPED)
10-04 20:39:55.356  3105 22150 E ExynosCameraMCPipe: [CAM_ID(0)][PIPE_3AA]-ERR(m_getBuffer[1948]):frameCount(691) : captureNodeCount == 0 || checkRet(0) != NO_ERROR. so, setFrameState(FRAME_STATE_SKIPPED)
10-04 20:39:55.419  3105  3382 E Surface : IGraphicBufferProducer::setBufferCount(0) returned Broken pipe
10-04 20:39:55.419  3105  3382 E ExynosCameraMemoryAllocator: ERR(setBufferCount):set_buffer_count failed [bufCount=0]
10-04 20:39:55.419  3105  3382 E ExynosCameraBufferManager: [CAM_ID(0)][SCP_BUF]-ERR(setBufferCount[2206]):m_allocator->setBufferCount(m_bufferCount(9)
```

-> 0)

Looks like the camera buffer dies out at some point, Think thats whats happening from the logs.

Thanks

Comment: The crash log can be helpful here.

Comment: you have an RGBA mat and you are trying to convert it to RGB2GRAY? Im not sure if that might be an issue

Comment: @TDG logcat dosent seem to have any errors at all, I think the native code is swallowing the errors, or some thing else is up.

Comment: @GPPK doing a "COLOR_RGBA2GRAY" didnt do it either

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak... But hard to tell, without the logs

Answer (score 1):

Seems issue is in

```
Mat gray = new Mat();
```

line, because it's create new `Mat` on every new camera frame. Try make `gray` variable global and create it once in `onCameraViewStarted()` and just use as `Imgproc.cvtColor()` parameter. Something like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {
    private Mat mRgba;
    private Mat mGray;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8U);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mGray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        return mGray;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did stumble across it a few days ago in a seperate question else where. This did the trick